# DOM paste event for files in Angular2

Tags: angular, clipboard

I'm trying to paste a csv file into a div container of an Angular 6 app. However the items property of my clipboard data is always empty. 
Has anybody successfully implemented this?

```
<div class="entries-list" (paste)="onPaste($event)"></div>
```

..

```
onPaste(event) {
    console.log(event.clipboardData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the pasted text, you must use getData method as follows:

```
onPaste(event) {
    console.log(event.clipboardData.getData('Text'));
}
```

Comment: As noted in my description I'm trying to get a csv file. Files should be in event.clipboardData.items as far as i know. This array is empty unfortunately.